# BOT Framework final confirmation prompt issue

Tags: bots, botframework

I am working on C# Bot Framework chat application.
During dialog handling i am taking some input from user and i add some details from my side and then i show that information to the user as given below, soon after i ask user a confirmation to continue "Do you really want to proceed ?" with Yes/No button, its a PromptChoice dialog.

- Your Availability From   09:00 AM
- Your Availability To 06:00 PM
  blah blah blah

The code is as below

```
 context.PostAsync("Information to display");

 PromptDialog.Confirm(context, OnConfirmation,
 "Do you really want to proceed ?",
 "Didn't get that",
 3,
 PromptStyle.Auto);
```

Now ideally information should be shown first and then user should be given prompt choice for selection(yes/No)  but sometime Prompt appears first before the information and as the window of chatbot is small, the user could not able to see prompt.

This occurs intermittently, why?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the answer? If the answer is helpful, can you please mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to await your `context.PostAsync("Information to display");`:

```
await context.PostAsync("Information to display");
```